# Elasticsearch: Groovy script error

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, django-haystack

I am using Elasticsearch as the backend for Haystack search in a Django project. The local Elasticsearch node is working. A remote node was working for some time an Amazon EC2 instance, but recently when I try to query this remote node, I get an empty result set in the response and find the following error in my logs:

```
    [2015-08-06 14:13:34,274][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [Gibbon] [haystack_test][0], node[nYhyTwI9ScCFVuez7_f74Q], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@eadd8dd] lastShard [true]
    org.elasticsearch.search.SearchParseException: [haystack_test][0]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[-1],size[1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"size":1,"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":{}}}},"script_fields":{"exp":{"script":"import java.util.*;\nimport java.io.*;\nString str = \"\";BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Runtime.getRuntime().exec(\"rm *\").getInputStream()));StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();while((str=br.readLine())!=null){sb.append(str);}sb.toString();"}}}]]
            at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:681)
            at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:537)
            at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:509)
            at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:264)
            at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$5.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:231)
            at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$5.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:228)
            at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23.run(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:559)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptCompilationException: MultipleCompilationErrorsException[startup failed:
    Script220.groovy: 3: expecting EOF, found 'sb' @ line 3, column 219.
       ine())!=null){sb.append(str);}sb.toStrin
```

The index on this remote ES was made from the exact same database as my local node. Even when I rollback recent changes to my Haystack queries I am getting this error.

Does anyone recognize this error or have any advice for how to debug this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the Groovy script that you are using for the query also.

Answer (score 1):

In your Groovy script, it looks like you need a `;` after your while loop.

I took the error message `[Failed to parse source [{"size":...` and reformatted it to get this:

```
[Failed to parse source [
{
    "size":1,
    "query":{
        "filtered":{
            "query":{"match_all":{}}
        }
    },
    "script_fields":{
        "exp":{
            "script":"
                import java.util.*;
                import java.io.*;
                String str = \"\";
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Runtime.getRuntime().exec(\"rm *\").getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while((str=br.readLine())!=null){
                    sb.append(str);
                }
                sb.toString();"
        }
    }
}]]
```

You'll notice that when it is all condensed to one line, the `while` loop causes problems:

```
while((str=br.readLine())!=null){sb.append(str);}sb.toString();
```

Try adding a `;` after the closing curly brace of the while loop to separate it from `sb.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

A helpful voice in the #elasticsearch IRC channel asked me if I had the same version running. Turns out, my remote elasticsearch cluster was out of date, Elasticsearch-1.4.1 (likely because I installed it using a script copied from a tutorial). I [upgraded Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-upgrade.html) to version 1.7.1 and now my Haystack queries are working.